# ReactJS: onClick handler on (grand) child component is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a simple page with nested react components using React, Redux. 
The underlying problem is not due to Redux / connect because if I try to play with code, I am able to dispatch the actions.

My problem is that when I click the image (or even a button), I don't see any event being triggered.

*render* method of grand child component:

```
<Fragment>
    <div key={blog.id} className='mb-1 mt-1'>
        <img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" 
         onClick={this.props.onPrefClick} />
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

I am new to React, Redux and have tried lot of solutions, that I could find on net, however nothing seems to work in my case and I am stuck on this now.

The way my components are:

```
<Dashboard\>
  <BlogList\>
```

Bloglist (parent component):

```
  <div>
     { this.props.blogs.map(this.renderBlogItem) }
  </div>
```

```
  updatePreference = (blog) => {
      console.log('1 Blog List this.updatePreference: clicked ');
  }

  renderBlogItem = blog => {
      return <BlogItem key={'m0' + blog.id} onBlogClick={() => this.updatePreference(blog)} />;
  }
```

BlogItem(Immediate Child component)

```
//this has some JSX static code and below child component
<PreferenceItem key={blog.id} onPrefClick={() => this.props.onBlogClick} />
```

PreferenceItem (grand child component)

```
//this has some JSX static code and below image with onClick
<div key={blog.id} className='mb-1 mt-1'>
    <img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" onClick={this.props.onPrefClick}/>
```

I was hoping that it should be a simple flow of events, but something is not working, I simplified it and changed Click functions in all the three components, changed, bind to fat arrow(=>) and other options, but whenever I click on image, `onClick` doesn't even getting fired (during playing with my code, when I used bind in grandchild component (with function defined in the same class), it fired the event, but during loading of the page - which is wrong

So something is not right here.

Sample [*working code*](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-http-5t3gv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), which has nested child at one level

I am following mainly official docs from [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) and some reference from the [freecodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36/):

**One more question**

I am now allowed to paste image - Chrome debug tool shows that image element's EventListener's handler is pointing to noop function and FunctionLocation is unknown
   *(why is this noop? This reflects that my bindings are not correct, but I am not able to fix it)*

And if I see the grand child's properties, it is pointing to onPrefClick

Please also direct me so I could debug this to reach the root cause?

> Element is
>   [image]
>   Component is now referring to onBlogClick
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors on this line.

```
<img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" onClick=this.props.onPrefClick}/>
```

Above it should be `onClick={() => this.props.onPrefClick()}` (Also did the modification here).

**The Fact**

When you need call a function in child component which is declared on a parent class you just need the pass the function to child component

```
<ChildComponent function={this.onClickFunction} />
```

Then you need to invoke the function in child component

```
<img onClick={() => this.props.function()}
```

In granchild component you should invoke the function.

```
<Fragment>
    <div key={blog.id} className='mb-1 mt-1'>
        <img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" 
         onClick={() => this.props.onPrefClick()} />
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Please correct me if something is not correct: After your suggestion, 
 **Parent:**  `<BlogItem key={blog.id} onBlogClick={this.updatePreference(blog)} />`, **Child:** `<PreferenceItem key={blog.id} onPrefClick={this.props.onBlogClick} />`, **Grand Child:** `<img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" onClick={() => this.props.onPrefClick()} />`  And after this change: the function declared in parent class is invoked during page load. I need this function when I click on image. It seems like my onClick has no impact. pls refer to d latest added img

Comment: Try this sandbox which shows how `img` associates with `onClick`
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-yalow-ru406?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: thanks, this sandbox code is working, and I slightly modified to add more components in the sandbox and that too works as expected, however same thing is not working in my code

Comment: thank you, after playing with your code, and looking carefully mine, it just worked like magic..

Comment: It was pleasure to help you :D

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue here - should be calling the function as well `() => this.props.onBlogClick()`:

```
<PreferenceItem key={blog.id} onPrefClick={() => this.props.onBlogClick} />
```

I guess this line should be the following:

```
<PreferenceItem key={blog.id} onPrefClick={this.props.onBlogClick} />
```

You were not calling the function, just returning it.

The other issue - maybe it is just a typo in your question but there is a missing `{` at `onClick`:

```
<img key={blog.id} src={ path_im } alt={'blog'} width="15" height="15" onClick=this.props.onPrefClick}/>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: @norbitial yes, that is a typo, thanks for highlighting it. And I removed the arrow function from PreferenceItem, still no change in onClick. I have added images as well now.